# React: Getting Element and apply onClick after render

Tags: reactjs

I am using react with a bootstrap theme which uses jquery.

The problem is that bootstraps dropdown menu and reacts onClick does not work together.

My solution is that i apply the onClick handler using jQuery in the componentDidUpdate() method of my component. This works as expected.

This does not work:

```
 <ul className="dropdown-menu pull-right">
     <li id="logout-button">
         <a href="#" onClick={this.logout.bind(this)}><i></i> Logout</a>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

This works:

```
public componentDidUpdate() {
  // workaround: problems with bootstraps dropdown onclick event
  $('#logout-button').click(() => {
      this.logout();
      return false;
  });
}
```

But how can i do this in pure react?

How can i retrieve my dom element in react and apply a onClick listener after render ?

Comment: You can use React `refs` to work around this, while letting the framework do some of the management. Remember to remove listeners when unmounting

Answer (score 0):

Using the [React's `refs`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html), you can obtain a reference to DOM elements inside the Component.

When binding events in `componentDidMount`, remember to remove your external listeners in `componentWillUnmount`.